# Exporting a Mixed (text and numeric) List to a File and Reimporting it Without Unwanted Changes

Tags: export, import

I found a few similar posts, but not close enough to give me an idea what to do. My problem is that I have a mixed format (data and string) nested list which I want to output to a file. I then want to edit the file by hand (only modest numeric changes), and reimport it back into the same program for use. I understand that I can retain formatting information using .mx format, but I understand that is not editable by a regular text editor. So, here is some test code, which illustrates my problem:

```
list = Table[0, {3}];

xORz = "x"; xzVec = {-6., -2., -1., -0.5, 0.};
lbls = {"x=\[PlusMinus]6", "x=\[PlusMinus]2", "x=\[PlusMinus]1", 
   "x=\[PlusMinus]0.5", "x = 0"};
plLmts = {z, 0.003, 10.}; plRng = {0., 2.3};
axLbls = {"z", "u(x,z)"}; type = "LogLinPair"; filen = "u";
list[[1]] = {axLbls, type, xORz, xzVec, ar, magn, lbls, plLmts, plRng,
    filen};

xORz = "x"; xzVec = {-6., -2., -1., -0.5, -0.2};
lbls = {"x=-6   ", "x=-2   ", "x=-1   ", "x=-0.5", "x=-0.2"};
plLmts = {z, 0.1, 10.}; plRng = {0.02, 0.8};
axLbls = {"z", "w(x,z)"}; type = "LogLogSngl"; filen = "w";
list[[2]] = {axLbls, type, xORz, xzVec, ar, magn, lbls, plLmts, plRng,
    filen};

xORz = "x"; xzVec = {-6., -2., -1., -0.5, 0.};
lbls = {"x=\[PlusMinus]6", "x=\[PlusMinus]2", "x=\[PlusMinus]1", 
   "x=\[PlusMinus]0.5", "x = 0"};
plLmts = {z, 0.01, 10.}; plRng = {0.001, 10.};
axLbls = {"z", "\[Psi](x,z)"}; type = "LogLogPair"; filen = "psi";
list[[3]] = {axLbls, type, xORz, xzVec, ar, magn, lbls, plLmts, plRng,
    filen};
Print[list]
Dimensions[list]
{axLbls, type, xORz, xzVec, ar, magn, lbls, plLmts, plRng, filen} = 
 list[[1]]
Print[Length[xzVec]];

Export["/Users/paul/Documents/stuff.dat", list, ""];
Clear[list];
list = Import["/Users/paul/Documents/stuff.dat", "Data"];
Print[list];
Dimensions[list]
{axLbls, type, xORz, xzVec, ar, magn, lbls, plLmts, plRng, filen} = 
 list[[1]]
Print[Length[xzVec]];
```

And here is a screenshot of my output:

[image: screenshot of output]

There are numerous differences between the exported and imported lists, including the dimensions which changed from (3,10) to (3,22), the "+-" symbols changed to "A with a circle above", quotes appear and extra commas appear. I have tried .csv format, and .txt format as well as .dat. Can anyone suggest a fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably this helps: `Export["file.txt", list, "Table"]`, then `Import["file.txt", "Table", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8", "FieldSeparators" -> "\t"]`.

Comment: @Alx. Thanks, I will try that.